What is the second quantized 1D non-interacting spinless Fermi gas Hamiltonian in position space?
So I understand that the Hamiltonian in momentum space for a 1D spinless fermion chain with $N$ sites $j = 1\cdots N$ is written:
$$ H = \sum_k c^\dagger_k c_k$$
with $c_k$ be the annihilation operator at some momentum $k = \frac{2\pi}{N}n$, here $n = 1\cdots N$ be the $n$-th wave mode.
To translate this into position space, we perform the Fourier transform:
$$c_{k(n)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_j e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}nj} c_j \\
c^\dagger_{k(n)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_j e^{i\frac{2\pi}{N}nj} c^\dagger_j $$
The problem is that I tried for 2 sites, and I got:
$$c_{k(1)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(- c_1 + c_2) \quad c_{k(2)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( c_1 + c_2) \\
c^\dagger_{k(1)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(- c^\dagger_1 + c^\dagger_2) \quad c^\dagger_{k(2)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( c^\dagger_1 + c^\dagger_2) \\
\begin{aligned}
\Rightarrow H &= c^\dagger_{k(1)} c_{k(1)} + c^\dagger_{k(2)} c_{k(2)} \\ &= c^\dagger_{1} c_{1} + c^\dagger_{2} c_{2}
\end{aligned}.$$
I thought I would get something like a hopping Hamiltonian $H = \sum_j c^\dagger_j c_{j+1} + c^\dagger_{j+1} c_j $ (because I heard that the Hubbard model shows Fermi gas behavior when the interaction is tuned to $0$, which means there's only the hopping term). But instead I got the exact same Hamiltonian back from momentum to real space, and it's just the number operator in each site. I tried for 3 sites and got the same thing.
Did I do something wrong, or did I misunderstand something here? Thank you!

What happens if you add an $\varepsilon_k$ into your momentum space Hamiltonian?

Ah I see, the hopping terms show up again with negative coefficients, and the number operator terms have positive coefficients, meaning the Hamiltonian favors hopping and disfavor sitting. But I tried for 3 sites, and there are non-zero coefficients for far-hopping like $c^\dagger_1 c_3$. It still doesn't reproduce the Hubbard model exactly. Is this physical?

You may have used the wrong dispersion relation. For nearest neighbour hopping, the dispersion relation is $\epsilon_k = -2t\cos k$

I see, thank you. So if I understand correctly, the free particle dispersion is actually $\epsilon^{\text{free}}_k=\frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}$, and the tight-binding $\epsilon^{\text{tb}}_k=-2t\cos k$ is an approximation of the 1D free fermi gas. In fact, with the correct $\epsilon^{\text{free}}_k$, far-hopping is possible, but we ignore this to get $\epsilon^{\text{tb}}_k$. Am I correct? But why do we do this?
